# May converts migrate to Israel?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, aliya-laaretz

I was wondering if a convert (someone who was not born a Jew) may, by the rules of the state of Israel, migrate to Israel (make aliyah, as defined by the State of Israel)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear whether you're asking about whether converts may migrate according to Jewish law, may migrate freely under the State of Israel's [Law of Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Return), both, or something else.

Comment: Just about anyone can migrate to Israel. That simply involves moving there. Do you mean if converts can make aliyah under the [Law of Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Return)?

Comment: Halakhically, anyone who is a Jew, Kehen, Lewi, Yisroel, or Jer/convert should move to Israel. The secular State of Israel doesn't even accept many, even Haredi, conversions made within Israel, because they need to have their own people and/or specific groups or authorities to put their stamp of approval on a conversion.

Comment: Converting outside of Israel, it would be better for the person just to get a statement from their Rabbi stating they are a member of the community and that he knows them to be Jewish. That will clarify things for the secular state.

Comment: Fast Furious, Please understand that the differences between the policies of the State of Israel and Jewish Law are many. It would really be beneficial for you to clarify your question. Who is the authority you are asking when you say "may migrate"?

Comment: I mean the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the only limitation is that the conversion is recognized by the Jewish Agency and the Ministry of Absorption.  Having your conversion recognized by the Ministry of Absorption can be either easier or harder than having it recognized by the Chief Rabbinate of Israel depending on the situation.

Comment: What is the criteria for that?

Comment: @FastFurious, You'll have to contact the Jewish Agency or another intermediary (like Nefesh B'Nefesh) for that information.

Comment: "the only limitation is that the conversion is recognized by the Jewish Agency and the Ministry of Absorption"? Gentiles can't migrate to Israel?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Israel's [Law of Return](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Immigration/Text_of_Law_of_Return.html) says that

> Every Jew has the right to come to this country as an oleh.

and defines "Jew" as

> a person who was born of a Jewish mother **or has become converted to Judaism** and who is not a member of another religion.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: +1, but you might add that gentiles can often migrate to Israel too (albeit not under the Law of Return).

Comment: @msh210, the question currently specifies "aliyah," which I think refers specifically to immigration to Israel by a Jew.